# PUT issues with JSON processing using JAXB under Jersey 2.2 with MOXy

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I have been stuck on this problem for a number of days and am now looking for some guidance to help solve the issue.  I have considerable experience with jax-ws under Metro, but this is my first adventure into jax-rs with Jersey.  To simplify the moving parts I took the jersey-examples-moxy code as a starting point.

I modified the example project to accept both XML and JSON.  I thought this would be simple, but I seem to be missing something because it has been a painful experience.  The code runs without issue when I am requesting "application/xml", and the GET will work for "application/json", but when I try to do a PUT with the JSON the server is returning a 500 status code.  I can see the JSON being sent in the PUT request, but the server seems to be having an issue accepting the JSON.

Here is the modified CustomerResource.java file segment.  All I did was add the MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON parameter to the Produces and Consumes annotations.

```
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerResource {

  private static Customer customer = createInitialCustomer();

  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
  }

  @PUT
  @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public void setCustomer(Customer c) {
    customer = c;
  }

  private static Customer createInitialCustomer() {
    Customer result = new Customer();

    result.setName("Jane Doe");
    result.setAddress(new Address("123 Any Street", "My Town"));
    result.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber("work", "613-555-1111"));
    result.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber("cell", "613-555-2222"));

    return result;
  }
}
```

I modified the MoxyAppTest.java file to request XML and JSON MediaTypes in separate tests:

```
@Test
public void testJaxBCustomer() throws Exception {
    final WebTarget webTarget = target().path("customer");

    Customer customer = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Customer.class);
    assertEquals("Jane Doe", customer.getName());

    customer.setName("Tom Dooley");
    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(Entity.xml(customer));
    assertEquals(204, response.getStatus());

    Customer updatedCustomer = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Customer.class);
    assertEquals(customer, updatedCustomer);
}

@Test
public void testJsonCustomer() throws Exception {
    final WebTarget webTarget = target().path("customer");

    Customer customer = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Customer.class);
    assertEquals("Tom Dooley", customer.getName());

    customer.setName("Bobby Boogie");
    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.json(customer));
    assertEquals(204, response.getStatus());

    Customer updatedCustomer = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Customer.class);
    assertEquals(customer, updatedCustomer);
}
```

In the App.java file I added the JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver class and a registerInstances() call in the createApp() method.  (Note taking this out does not change result).

```
public static ResourceConfig createApp() {
    return new ResourceConfig().packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.xmlmoxy")
            .register(new MoxyXmlFeature())
            .registerInstances(new JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver());      
}

@Provider
final static class JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        final MoxyJsonConfig configuration = new MoxyJsonConfig();

        Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
        namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi");

        configuration.setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper);
        configuration.setNamespaceSeparator(':');

        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Here is the log segment showing the "application/xml" PUT was successful with a status of 204:

```
Aug 23, 2013 1:23:50 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread main
3 > PUT http://localhost:9998/customer
3 > Accept: application/xml
3 > Content-Type: application/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer><personal-info><name>Tom Dooley</name></personal-info><contact-info><address><city>My Town</city><street>123 Any Street</street></address><phone-number type="work">613-555-1111</phone-number><phone-number type="cell">613-555-2222</phone-number></contact-info></customer>

Aug 23, 2013 1:23:50 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 4 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread main
4 < 204
4 < Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 05:23:50 GMT
```

Now for the "application/json" logs:

```
Aug 23, 2013 1:23:51 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread main
3 > PUT http://localhost:9998/customer
3 > Accept: application/json
3 > Content-Type: application/json
{"personal-info":{"name":"Bobby Boogie"},"contact-info":{"address":{"city":"My Town","street":"123 Any Street"},"phone-number":[{"type":"work","value":"613-555-1111"},{"type":"cell","value":"613-555-2222"}]}}

Aug 23, 2013 1:23:51 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 4 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread main
4 < 500
4 < Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 05:23:50 GMT
4 < Content-Length: 0
4 < Connection: close
```

As you can see the server is returning a status code of 500.  The Grizzly test container is not generating a log capturing any exception information, and it looks like nothing is returned in the 500 response.  Is there a way I can get the additional exception details?

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider making your question shorter. You will be more probable to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what causes this issue is a combination of:

- `@XmlPath` annotation on `Customer` bean, and
- `namespacePrefixMapper` that you're setting into `MoxyJsonConfig`

which causes a `NullPointerException` during (un)marshalling JSON. This has been fixed in nightly versions (`2.5.1` and `2.6.1`) of MOXy. You can download it from [Nightly Builds](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php) page.

If you don't want to change the version of MOXy at the moment, simply remove this line

```
configuration.setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper);
```

from `JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver` and you should be fine.

Regarding the logging issue - we know about it and it's beings fixed (should be resolved in `Jersey 2.3`).

Comment: In the time I have been stuck I have rewritten the example without the @XmlPath annotations and the problem still exists, however, removing the **configuration.setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper)** line fixed the issue.  I could have sworn I tried that in my previous attempts, but looks like I did not.  Thank you very much,  your help is greatly appreciated!