# Issues with JSON processing using JAXBElement under Jersey 2.2 with MOXy

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, moxy, jaxbelement

I extended the *jersey-examples-moxy* code to use an XML schema definition instead of the JAXB annotated beans.  The xjc compiled XML schema produces XML and JSON encodings identical to the original example.

I followed the jersey instructions and used the *ObjectFactory* to generate the *JAXBElement Customer* object representation within CustomerResource.java.  I also modified the client as described.  I also incorporated the fix described in [PUT issues with JSON processing using JAXB under Jersey 2.2 with MOXy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396726/put-issues-with-json-processing-using-jaxb-under-jersey-2-2-with-moxy)

The **MediaType.APPLICATION_XML** functions perfectly, and **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON** works for GETs, but the client is failing to marshall JSON on a PUT with "MessageBodyWriter not found".  The following exception is thrown:

```
testJsonCustomer(org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jaxbmoxy.MoxyAppTest)  Time elapsed: 0.113 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement, genericType=class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:191)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
at org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.aroundWriteTo(LoggingFilter.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1005)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:430)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:290)
```

Here is how I modified CustomerResource.java:

```
private static ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public JAXBElement<Customer> getCustomer() {
    return factory.createCustomer(customer);
}

@PUT
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public JAXBElement<Customer> setCustomer(Customer c) {
    customer = c;      
    return factory.createCustomer(customer);
}
```

Here is how I am making the PUT request (same as for the functioning XML):

```
@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
    clientConfig.register(new MoxyXmlFeature());
}

@Test
public void testJsonCustomer() throws Exception {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    final WebTarget webTarget = target().path("customer");

    // Target customer entity with GET and verify inital customer name.
    Customer customer = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Customer.class);
    assertEquals("Tom Dooley", customer.getPersonalInfo().getName());

    // Update customer name with PUT and verify operation successful.
    customer.getPersonalInfo().setName("Bobby Boogie");
    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.json(factory.createCustomer(customer)));
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    // Target customer entity with GET and verify name updated.
    Customer updatedCustomer = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Customer.class);
    assertEquals(customer.getPersonalInfo().getName(), updatedCustomer.getPersonalInfo().getName());
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is on this line:

```
Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.json(factory.createCustomer(customer)));
```

Basically you're passing `JAXBElement` to `Entity#json` method but the runtime doesn't have information about the generic type, you need to provide it. That's what [GenericEntity<T>](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) class is for:

```
webTarget
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .put(Entity.json(new GenericEntity<JAXBElement<Customer>>(factory.createCustomer(customer)) {}));
```

Comment: This definitely solved my issue.  Is there a specific reason why the runtime for json does not handle the JAXBElement the same way the xml runtime does? Any chance you have a reference to this somewhere so i can do some further reading to avoid additional pitfalls in the differences?